# Importing GeoJSON into MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, geojson

I'm just trying out some stuff with GeoJSON's by figuring out how to import them into MongoDB. Here is a snippet of the JSON data that I'm trying to import:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "crs": {
        "type": "name",
        "properties": {
            "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
        }
    },
    "source": "© GeoBasis-DE / BKG 2013 (Daten verändert)",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "RS": "051580004004",
                "DES": "Stadt",
                "GEN": "Erkrath",
                "EWZ_M": 20929,
                "EWZ_W": 22883,
                "SHAPE_AREA": 26441754.911268
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            6.88238674728364,
                            51.24166234476658
                        ],
                        [
                            6.881975279589705,
                            51.23757802188462
                        ],
                        [
                            6.891756626701045,
                            51.23929422878399
                        ],
                        [
                            6.903180857084263,
                            51.23707789012778
                        ],
                        [
                            6.908259412237354,
                            51.24206723420193
                        ],
                        [
                            6.918977412277895,
                            51.24041847413137
                        ],
                        [
                            6.926662904165135,
                            51.24253596694298
                        ],
                        [
                            6.937590326994132,
                            51.23093391057761
                        ],
                        [
                            6.94295724765998,
                            51.2299892278866
                        ],
                        [
                            6.939417113978845,
                            51.227341409094315
                        ],
                        [
                            6.951333593915336,
                            51.22740615125517
                        ],
                        [
                            6.950253526637431,
                            51.224656373607054
                        ],
                        [
                            6.955765647972802,
                            51.22167757046095
                        ],
                        [
                            6.964606469495985,
                            51.22457614378809
                        ],
                        [
                            6.975480633820623,
                            51.223046741435965
                        ],
                        [
                            6.973404761769492,
                            51.22089502422256
                        ],
                        [
                            6.980214287180364,
                            51.21998473062592
                        ],
                        [
                            6.982741542191386,
                            51.214167748907066
                        ],
                        [
                            6.994804384322499,
                            51.215655729126155
                        ],
                        [
                            6.994747626413055,
                            51.21224925095131
                        ],
                        [
                            6.985928005605313,
                            51.20743852466108
                        ],
                        [
                            6.98828820437737,
                            51.20347146797952
                        ],
                        [
                            6.944606700602787,
                            51.198908942197114
                        ],
                        [
                            6.943253716046289,
                            51.19637267292547
                        ],
                        [
                            6.937329237188316,
                            51.19846226521679
                        ],
                        [
                            6.932905519738434,
                            51.194111787062006
                        ],
                        [
                            6.907388585403191,
                            51.19594285093562
                        ],
                        [
                            6.903803051706552,
                            51.20313804926765
                        ],
                        [
                            6.910551758112292,
                            51.21099091708282
                        ],
                        [
                            6.878932812936605,
                            51.21491884904021
                        ],
                        [
                            6.872564112818471,
                            51.219486802570856
                        ],
                        [
                            6.873244797535404,
                            51.226155851357795
                        ],
                        [
                            6.878496898776498,
                            51.22869664243089
                        ],
                        [
                            6.872981880136851,
                            51.232966792978665
                        ],
                        [
                            6.871618163754948,
                            51.24209470504303
                        ],
                        [
                            6.88238674728364,
                            51.24166234476658
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "RS": "051160000000",
                "DES": "Stadt",
                "GEN": "Mönchengladbach",
                "EWZ_M": 123662,
                "EWZ_W": 131172,
                "SHAPE_AREA": 170540962.920759
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                     .....
                     .....
```

I want now to import this data into my MongoDB instance. When I tried the following, I ran into some errors:

```
mongoimport --db /Users/joe/mongodb-data -c points --file "gemeinden_simplify200.geojson" --jsonArray

connected to: 127.0.0.1
assertion: 13106 nextSafe(): { $err: "Invalid ns [/Users/joe/mongodb-data.points]", code: 16256 }
```

Comment: The `--db` argument is not the "path" to the database or stored data but the name of the database container. The default db is `test`, but is otherwise the equivalent `use db` that you want. Also if you want to work with geospatial queries in MongoDB then a "FeatureCollection" is not a supported type anyway and would need to be broken down to the individual objects.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to get that done?

Comment: Not sure what was not clear here. See `mongoimport` documentation for [`--db`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/program/mongoimport/#cmdoption--db). But as stated, this really won't help you ( that much beyond RTFM ) if you want to use the data in a meaningful way. For that you need to read and understand [GeoJSON Objects](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/geojson/) in the manual as well. As that will tell you the valid types that you can query on in a meaningful way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to try-

```
 mongoimport --db test -c points --file "gemeinden_simplify200.geojson" --jsonArray
```

Here `test` is database name.

Comment: This isn't correct. This imports an array of `features`, not a `FeatureCollection`. You need to extract the features first.